# String reverse with x64 SSE / AVX registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, avx2

I'm trying to write SIMD assembly instructions to reverse a string between 16 and 32 bytes of length. The below reverses a string exactly 32 bytes long but doesn't take care of anything shorter. Is there an AVX / SSE way of doing this better in a much more concise manner? I effectively need a bswap for xmm or ymm.

Rdx is pointing somewhere in memory with a null terminated string that I'm wanting to reverse. Upon reversal I want to overwrite the string with it's reversed version at the same address.

```
movdqu xmm0, [rdx]
pshufd xmm0,xmm0, 0x1B    
pshuflw xmm0,xmm0, 0xB1
pshufhw xmm0, xmm0, 0xB1
movdqa xmm1,xmm0
psrlw xmm1, 8
psllw xmm0, 8    
por xmm0,xmm1 

movdqu xmm2, [rdx +0x10]
pshufd xmm2,xmm2, 0x1b    
pshuflw xmm2,xmm2, 0xB1
pshufhw xmm2, xmm2, 0xB1
movdqa xmm3,xmm2
psrlw xmm3, 8
psllw xmm2, 8    
por xmm2,xmm3

movdqu [rdx], xmm2
movdqu [rdx+0x10], xmm0
```

Comment: Load a control vector for `pshufb` to reverse a whole vector with one shuffle.  You only get 1 shuffle / clock throughput on Intel, but `vpshufb ymm` is still a single uop.  So load 32 bytes, byte-reverse the 128-bit lanes with `vpshufb`, then store the two halves separately with `vextracti128`.  (Or do narrow loads and a wide store.)

Comment: I attempted that earlier without success. Is there better documentation than the x86 manual that you can point me toward? Everything I find is a c++ intrinsic way of doing it and the manual itself isn't the clearest. I'm quite new to using this extension.

Comment: Also, I greatly appreciate the response.

Comment: You could write in intrinsics and look at compiler output.  Or Intel's x86 manual is very clear (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb). Unfortunately somewhat bloated with AVX512 versions of everything these days, though, so consider looking at an older PDF of vol.2.  Agner Fog's optimizing assembly guide is nice, though: https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Thank you man. I greatly appreciate the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Load a control vector for `pshufb` to reverse a whole vector with one shuffle.**  You only get 1 shuffle / clock throughput on Intel, but `vpshufb ymm` is still a single uop.  (https://agner.org/optimize/)

So load 32 bytes, byte-reverse the 128-bit lanes with `vpshufb`, then store the two halves separately with `vextracti128`.  Or do narrow loads and a wide store which is probably better for avoiding store-forwarding stalls.

Or use an extra shuffle to swap halves of a YMM between 32-byte load / 32-byte store.  (e.g. `vpermq` or `vperm2i128` to lane swap, before or after `vpshufb`).

```
default rel

byte_rev_32:
    ...
    vmovdqu      xmm0, [rdx + 16]         ; 1 uop
    vinserti128  ymm0, ymm0, [rdx], 1     ; 2 uops: load + any vector-ALU port
    ; lane-swapping load that doesn't cost any port-5-only shuffle uops

    ; then in-lane byte reverse
    vpshufb      ymm0, ymm0, [byte_reverse]   ; 1 uop (with micro-fused load)

    vmovdqu      [rdx], ymm0
    ...

section .rodata:
 align 32
 byte_reverse: db 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
               db 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

**Or if you're doing this in a loop, you should hoist the load of the shuffle-control vector.  e.g. `VBROADCASTI128  ymm1, [byte_reverse]`** so you only need a 16-byte constant in memory.  Broadcast-loads with dword and larger granularity are just as cheap as regular loads, on Intel CPUs.

AVX512VBMI (CannonLake / Ice Lake) has lane-crossing `vpermb` that can byte-reverse a 32 or 64-byte vector in 1 instruction.

Or with only SSSE3 for `pshufb`, not AVX2, simply load both 16-byte halves, swap them separately, and store them separately.

Comment: Did you mean for vinserti128 to have 3 arguments? The documentation is saying we need 4 but didn't know if this is shorthand for something you meant in this particular case.

Comment: @kr1tzb1tz: Oh right, that wasn't intentional.  But NASM syntax does allow omitting the first source when it's the same as the destination, so I think if you'd assembled my original version you would have gotten this anyway.